# What is the google tricks on their logo?

Tags: html, image

When I search in Google, instead of their main page, when I look at their logo, and copy the image path, it shows that:

```
http://www.google.com/images/nav_logo91.png
```

Well, it is not a logo only, it have many icon as well. Is there any reason why Google use this way to do so? any results or just for showcasing their technique skill? Also, how can only show a part of a image only? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a sprite.  Doing this can reduce file size and load time.

You can splice the image using JavaScript or using CSS (CSS being the more popular choice).  You can make the element with a `div` tag, then set the `background-image` property to the URL you've specified.  Then use the `background-position` property to align it appropriately.  Lastly, set the expected `width` and `height` of the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

Its called CSS sprites. A lot of websites use this technique, where in all (decorative) images on the site are contained in a single image.

This single image tends to be smaller in size than the sum of all the individual images (each image holds its own color table). Also, fetching a single image from the server means lesser HTTP server requests.

The large image is then placed as backgrounds in div's and manipulated using `background-position` and other CSS properties to ensure only the portion of the sprite shows that is required.

Answer (score 2):

It's like animuson has already explained, they're called CSS sprites, to expand a little they are used to prevent excess HTTP Requests.

By having just one image to load, it is cached and then the website can use that one image for multiple backgrounds but only make certain areas viewable by using background-position.

A good explanation is here: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/